# How can I find out which (concrete) types satisfy a set of typeclass constraints?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, ghci

Given a number of typeclass constraints:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
import Data.Array.Unboxed(Ix,IArray,UArray)

type IntLike a = (Ord a, Num a, Enum a, Show a, Ix a, IArray UArray a)
```

How can I find out which types satisfy `IntLike`, i.e. all the mentioned constraints *jointly*?

I can puzzle together the information needed from the output of ghci's `:info` command, and then doublecheck my work by calling (or having ghci typecheck)

```
isIntLike :: IntLike -> Bool
isIntLike = const True
```

at various types, e.g. `isIntLike (3::Int)`.

Is there a way to get ghci to do this for me?

I'm currently interested in concrete types, but wouldn't mind having a more general solution which also does clever stuff with unifying contexts!

Comment: You can do this using template haskell: `main = print $(reify ''Show >>= stringE . show)`. This won't work for type synonyms - rather, reify returns the AST representing the type synonym itself, without expanding it. You can check for type synonyms which are constraints, extract the constraints of which that type synonym consists, and continue `reify`ing those.

Comment: Right, that seems to contain all the information I need to take the intersection, thanks! I'll what I can whip up, but I have to say that hacking GHCi almost seems more practical :-)

Comment: @user2407038 can you turn that comment into an answer as i tseems to have answered the qeustion?

Answer (score 1):

Community Wiki answer based on the comments:

You can do this using template haskell.

```
main = print $(reify ''Show >>= stringE . show).
```

This won't work for type synonyms - rather, reify returns the AST representing the type synonym itself, without expanding it. You can check for type synonyms which are constraints, extract the constraints of which that type synonym consists, and continue reifying those.

Comment: Worth pointing out this can be done just in GHCi with `-XTemplateHaskell` on using `$(Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.reify ''Show >>= Language.Haskell.TH.Lib.stringE . show)`